# How to split parsers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have question.

I’m writing an application which parsing 10 webpages. I described each parser as a method of “parsercontroller”. The next step is to run 10 threads with 10 parsers, after the action is done I need to run another process.

1. I want to split each parser to separate class? How can I store all 10 parsers? Like separate namespace or smth else? Could you give me an advice how to move forward?
2. How can I run another process after the all parsers is done? In what way I need to move?

Thanks a lot, I appreciate all the help)

### Update

#### Source code:

parser_controller.rb

```
class ParserController < ApplicationController
  def parser1 
    #parse a lot of data (big parser)
  end

  def parser2 
    #parse a lot of data (big parser)
  end
  
  private 
  
  def helper_for_checking_data
     # check data when filling database.
  end

  def cleanup_database
     #clean db by cron every day
  end
end
```

How can I split all of this methods, because I don't know good practices.

Comment: 1. What is the problem with creating separate classes? Give each class a well-chosen unique name and you’re good to go. A module (not namespace) might be a good idea too. 2. You join one thread after the other and once that loop returns (thus all threads are done) you run the other process.

Comment: @idmean I'm using Ruby on Rails and don't understand how to do it. Should I create 10 controllers and call all of them inside "parsercontroller" or how it should be?

Comment: Can you please share source code of any two parsers so I can guide you how to design and place classes?

Comment: @AmitPatel I've done it.

Comment: You havn't share source code of parsers. You just shared placeholder actions of controller.

Comment: Do you need to wait for the parsers to complete to render a view? If not, you could turn these into ActionJobs (which would also split them up into separate classes and separate them logically).